# running macOS terminal using c# process class

Tags: c#, macos, terminal, process

I am trying to run the macOS terminal using the process class in c# with this code

```
Process compiler = new Process() ;
compiler.StartInfo.FileName = "/bin/bash";
compiler.StartInfo.Arguments = "pwd";
compiler.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
compiler.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
compiler.Start();
UnityEngine.Debug.Log(compiler.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
compiler.WaitForExit();
```

this just does nothing. for the printing statement it prints a blank everytime.

Comment: why not just run `pwd` directly? Get rid of the `Arguments` and set `FileName` to `"/bin/pwd"`

Comment: If you must use `bash`, set the `Arguments` to `"-c pwd"`

Comment: @Andy my goal here is not to run pwd, but to run a mediapipe bazel build using the command "bazel-bin/media......ve.pbtxt". It would be nice if I just had the full functionality of terminal. I tried /bin/pwd just so I would have something working, but even that is displaying a blank output, and setting Arguments to "-c pwd" also just results in a blank output.